# use underscore countBy for nested property of objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, group-by, underscore.js

In javascript,I have an array of objects like the following:

```
[
  {
    "fields": {
      "assignee": {
        "email": "emailid1",
        "name": "name1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "fields": {
      "assignee": {
        "email": "emailid2",
        "name": "name2"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "fields": {
      "assignee": {
        "email": "emailid1",
        "name": "name1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Now I want to groupby/count the number of objects based on email.
So for the above array of objects it should return me the following:

```
emailid1 : 2
emialid2 : 1
```

Is there anyway of doing this using underscore.js ? I found [underscore countby](http://underscorejs.org/#countBy) to be useful,but couldn't figure out how to use it in this case since I am having nested object properties here.

Comment: Post valid data structure before asking about manipulations with it. But in any case simple reduce would work here, but you can use underscore too of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following implementation returns `{emailid1: 2, emailid2: 1}`:

```
_.countBy(data, function(e) { 
  return e.fields.assignee.email 
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to also return the name along with the email?